# Changing the window style of a shelled program

Tags: excel, vba, shell

In Excel VBA, is it possible to change the window style of a shelled program?

Here's the situation in detail:

At the click of a command button, the user should be able to load a third-party scanning program. The software path and file are specified in a named cell called settings_scanningsoftware, as you can see below. However, I'm using the Shell program, which doesn't wait for the third-party software to load before continuing. If it did, my life would be easier. For that reason, I throw up a dialog box in Excel telling the user to wait for the software to load and then ready the item to be scanned before they click Ok. And, since I throw up a dialog box, I load the scanning program minimized so they can see the dialog box (instead of it being hidden behind the software window and they're wondering why nothing's happening). With me so far?

However, once they click Ok, I want Excel to give control to the scanning software and give it a regular-sized window. There's my problem: once the software is loaded minimized, I can't seem to change the window style to give it a regular window.

Here's my code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim ScannerShell As Integer
ScannerShell = Shell(Range("settings_scanningsoftware").Value, **vbMinimizedNoFocus**)
If (ScannerShell <> 0) Then
    Dim MessageBoxValue As Integer
    MessageBoxValue = MsgBox("When you're ready to scan the receipt, click Ok.", vbOKCancel, "Scan receipt")
    If (MessageBoxValue = vbOK) Then
        ScannerShell = Shell(Range("settings_scanningsoftware").Value, **vbNormal**)
        AppActivate ScannerShell, False
        SendKeys ("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB} ")
    End If
End If
```

Notice I've got the vbMinimizedNoFocus bolded above so that the software loads minimized and the user can see the upcoming dialog box. Once they click Ok, though, the software's window should be normalized. But Excel won't do me that favour.

Is there a way to change the window style after it's loaded?

Never mind the SendKeys command. I put that in there to get the scanner to automatically scan once everything is in place (the key sequence is incomplete, but one problem at a time). I know SendKeys is not a great way of sending commands to a program, but I'll figure that out once I get this window style thing fixed.

Does anyone have any solutions for me? Thanks.

Comment: Not using `Shell`. That would launch a new instance of the scanning software, not do anything to affect the existing one. You can use the WinAPI to send messages to the minimized application (using `ShowWindow()`, for instance), if you can get a window handle (HWND) to it.

Comment: Also, just FYI: Formatting such as **bold** does not work inside code blocks, as you can see. It's better just to add a regular code comment either above or on the line you want to point out, because the effort to **bold** results in a syntax error in the code.